# Query with a PHP foreach using OR and LIKE %?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-like

I have sort of a tricky problem, and I want to see if there is an easier way about solving it.

I have let's say

```
$numbers= $_GET['numbers']; //resulting in $numbers=array(1,2,3)
```

- The count in the array may vary depending on the $_GET value...
- These need to search using **'%" . $number. "%'** because there might be more than one number in the row separated by commas

**My ideal result** would perform a search for the $numbers(1,2,3) with:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE numbers LIKE('%1%' OR '%2%' OR '%2%')
```

Comment: The `_utf8 USING latin1` smells suspiciously of cargo cult programming. Any specific reason why you can't do without that?

Comment: It's the only way I know how to search anywhere within a row ... is there a better way?, thats just what mysql does by default when I use the LIKE%...% search

Comment: As I thought, cargo cult. `LIKE %42%` works just fine, get rid of `_utf8` and `USING latin1`.

Comment: Haha thanks! I guess when I had tried it the other way a while back I must have made a syntax error and went back to the 'old' way

Comment: `there might be more than one number in the row separated by commas` ...then you are going to need a word boundary technique to prevent a search of  `1` from match `18,26`. This sounds a like an XY Problem that would be avoided by improving the database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to inject many `OR` operators for each element of the Array. Instead you can use [rlike (the regex matcher operator of MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) and simplify your code to a great extent like this:

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3);
$sql = 'SELECT * from `database` WHERE number rlike "^'.implode('|', $numbers).'$"';
// $sql becomes: SELECT * from `database` WHERE number rlike "^1|2|3$"
```

Comment: Yes please make sure to use anchors `^` and `$` as in the built regex as in my last edit.

Comment: is that necessary? I just tried it without and it worked great

Comment: Yes it works with anchors as as well. But just keep in mind this regex `"1|2|3"` will match `1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 33, 17, 39, 26` etc etc. You see whatever rows have `1, 2 or 3` present in number field will match. However same behavior will be there for your current approach and in other suggested answers as well. So it entirely depends upon your needs whether you want to make your code restrictive by using anchors or not.

Comment: Thanks ya it won't matter for what I'm using it for. Thanks so much this not only solved the entire problem, but will save time and space!

Answer (score 2):

```
$like_part = implode(' OR ', array_map(function($i) {
        return "(_utf8 '%{$i}%' USING latin1)";
    }, $numbers)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the foreach to build the where string, then add it to the query.

```
$query = '...';

$where = '';
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $where .= ...
}

$query .= $where;
```

I won't mention that you should [normalize your tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and use prepared queries.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
<?php
$numbers = array(1,2,3);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE numbers LIKE ('%" . implode("%' OR '%", $numbers) . "%')";
```

Resulting this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE numbers LIKE ('%1%' OR '%2%' OR '%3%')
```

Answer (score 1):

to the effect of:

$query = "select * from `table` where condition like ('text before '".implode("' text after text before'", $array)." ' text after')"

$query = "select * from `table` where numbers like (\"_utf8 '%" . implode("%' using latin1\", $_GET['numbers']) . "%' using latin1 OR _utf8 '%\")

[not sure if implode is needle/haystack or vice versa]

Comment: I think you got it right...its usually implode("," $var).
Thanks Lemme try it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
1 - SELECT * FROM b AS B INNER JOIN a AS A ON A.a=B.a WHERE A.a RLIKE '^1-|^2-|^3'
2 - SELECT * FROM b AS B INNER JOIN a AS A ON A.a=B.a WHERE (A.a LIKE '1-%' OR A.a LIKE '2-%' OR A.a LIKE '3-%')
```

First query took around

1. Memory usage = It is taking time
2. Execution time = It is taking time
3. PHPMYADMIN   Showing rows 0 - 24 (138 total, Query took 1.1243 seconds.) - Tested with very less data than through direct PHP script

Second query took around

1. Memory usage = 1198.0807113647 MB
2. Execution time = 30.719851970673 Seconds
3. PHPMYADMIN - Showing rows 0 - 24 (138 total, Query took 0.0018 seconds.)  - Tested with very less data than through direct PHP script

Foreach took around

1. Memory usage = 972.3137588501 MB
2. Execution time = 10.898797988892 Seconds

Configuration

1. 32GB RAM
2. Intel I9 - 10th gen CPU@2.81GHz
3. PHP 7.3
4. MYSQL - 5.7.31
5. Table size - 2M million data generated by SQL procedure
6. SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache'; // YES
7. Fetched data size 275093
8. Indexing - Available
9. Count of variable in LIKE operator 4739 `(i.e. 1,2,3... in RLIKE '^1-|^2-|^3....etc')`
10. Memory uage calculated by php function `memory_get_usage();`

Objections welcomes.

Comment: Execution time is irrelevant if none of the answers on this page prevent over-matching. @Anubhava states under his answer that a search for `2` will match `7,23` -- this is an unreliable solution to a database design that is not fit for purpose.  I don't see enough details to rely on your benchmark results.  How many rows? Where are indexes? Is query caching turned off? What version of mysql did you run this on?  What php environment did you test in?

Comment: Updated the configuration details